# Domain Name Issues – Subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, url, relative-path, subdirectory, case-insensitive

I have two issues that I should know the answer to. This is a WordPress website.

1. The client now wants the subdirectory to be the primary website, not a subdomain (i.e. **http://www.example.com/TEST**). But wherever I already have code for relative URLs (i.e. **/subscribe**), it links back to **http://www.example.com/subscribe** rather than **http://www.example.com/TEST/subscribe**. How do I prevent this?
2. Also, I cannot remember how to make the subdirectory not case sensitive. Right now, only http://www.example.com/TEST works but http://www.example.com/test does not.

Answer (score 0):

1. I can't think of anything that'll turn references to `/subscribe` to `subscribe` other than Javascript or static rewrites of the source files.
2. I think this depends on your web server.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified, but if you are running on Apache httpd, you can accomplish #2 using mod_speling: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_speling.html

The configuration syntax is:

```
CheckCaseOnly On
```

For #1 ... well, that's what a URL of /subscribe means, so if you don't want it to do that, use 'subscribe' or './subscribe' instead of '/subscribe'.

If you're saying that *all* of the content for the site is in fact served out of the /TEST subdirectory, I would encourage you to change your site's DocumentRoot to point to that directory, rather than trying to alter all of your URLs.